# show/hide div javascript triggering div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so Im using this code for show/hiding 3 divs. and it works like a charm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookieValue(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var redEl = $('input[value="red"]');
    var greenEl = $('input[value="green"]');
    var blueEl = $('input[value="blue"]');

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('red=') != -1) {
        redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("red")));
    }

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
        greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
    }

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('blue=') != -1) {
        blueEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("blue")));
    }

    $(".red").toggle(redEl.prop("checked"));
    $(".green").toggle(greenEl.prop("checked"));
    $(".blue").toggle(blueEl.prop("checked"));

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

        var expiryDate = new Date();
        expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
        expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".red").toggle(this.checked);
            document.cookie="red=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".green").toggle(this.checked);
            document.cookie="green=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".blue").toggle(this.checked);
            document.cookie="blue=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i want to add little bit more to it. 
here is what i want:

Div red is 50% width
Green is 50% width
Blue is 100% width.

what i want is something like: If green is showing/checked, then div red is 50%. if div green is unchecked/turned of, then div red changes to 100%. the blue one is normal all the time and nothing changed with that.

Comment: Any chance you can create a jsFiddle of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Try It: Its 100% workable...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box{
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .red{ background: #ff0000; }
        .green{ background: #00ff00; }
        .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getCookieValue(a) {
        var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
        return b ? b.pop() : '';
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var redEl = $('input[value="red"]');
        var greenEl = $('input[value="green"]');
        var blueEl = $('input[value="blue"]');

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('red=') != -1) {
            redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("red")));
        }

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
            greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
        }
        if ($('#chkgreen').is(':Checked')) {
            $(".red").css('width', '50%');
        }
        else {
            $(".red").css('width', '96.8%');
        }
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('blue=') != -1) {
            blueEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("blue")));
        }

        $(".red").toggle(redEl.prop("checked"));
        $(".green").toggle(greenEl.prop("checked"));
        $(".blue").toggle(blueEl.prop("checked"));

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

            var expiryDate = new Date();
            expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
            expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".red").toggle(this.checked);
                document.cookie="red=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                $(".green").toggle(this.checked);
                document.cookie="green=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                $(".blue").toggle(this.checked);
                document.cookie="blue=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red" id="chkred" />
                red</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green" id="chkgreen"/>
                green</label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue" id="chkblue"/>
                blue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
        <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
        <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello. im really sorry i forgot to mention that its only 50% width when @media max-width: 991px; is turned on. so above that the divs are 100%. is it possible to do something about it? Im sorry i didn't mention it in the beginning.

Comment: hello again. i tried your code to to se how it works. yours work fine, but the toggle doesn't work. like "check" and "uncheck" doesn't change the value from 96% to 50% unless i reload the page. Can you pleas check it yourself to? its really weird, but the value for .red box only changes when i reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below mentioned solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #00ff00; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

var redEl = $('input[value="red"]');
var greenEl = $('input[value="green"]');
var blueEl = $('input[value="blue"]');

if (document.cookie.indexOf('red=') != -1) {
    redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("red")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
    greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('blue=') != -1) {
    blueEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("blue")));
}

$(".red").toggle(redEl.prop("checked"));
$(".green").toggle(greenEl.prop("checked"));
$(".blue").toggle(blueEl.prop("checked"));

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
    expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

    if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
        $(".red").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="red=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;           
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
        $(".green").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="green=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
        if(this.checked) 
            $(".red").css("width","50%");
        else
            $(".red").css("width","100%");

    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
        $(".blue").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="blue=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
 </div>
 <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
   <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. im really sorry i forgot to mention that its only 50% width when @media max-width: 991px; is turned on. so above that the divs are 100%. is it possible to do something about it? Im sorry i didn't mention it in the beginning.

Comment: Hi again. i have a problem now, unfortunately. i just noticed it.
If "green" is checked, and i reload the page, the width: 50% for red doesn't get activated. when i turn green of and on again, then the width 50% works. its like red doesn't red the values 50% and 100%. can you pleas help with that?

Comment: Hello @Peter
I think you will be store in database. You can do easily when you need page reload and checkbox will checked. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: How Can i store it in database? Im not sure what you are talking about. Did you understand what i ment? Like the style wont activate for .red unless i check/uncheck the Green one first

Comment: Can you try this in documnet ready function,
if($(".green").is(":checked"))
 {
  $(".red").css("width","50%");
 }
 else
 {
  $(".red").css("width","100%");
 }
Let me know.

Comment: This works only half. now it loads a width 100% in the html source in style=" " tag, but its always 100%. no matter if the green is checked or unchecked its still 100%, but after i check/uncheck the green, it changes.  I dont know if its important to mention that as standard i have in my input tag as check="checked" turned on for the green. so as standard its always checked.

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

just add a small if condition in your click event work

```
if($(this).val() == 'green'){
      width = ($(this).prop('checked'))?'50%':'100%';
      $(".red").css("width",width)
}
```

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfd485qg/2/) 
to make this work on page load you need to add some code where you reading cookies and making check box checked as follow.

```
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
        greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
        if(getCookieValue("green")){ // if green checkbox is check 
           $(".red").css("width","50%") // make it,s width 50%
        }
     }
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfd485qg/4/)

Comment: Hi. thank you. so i tried it, and i have the same problem with this. it won't load when i reload the page, but when i check/uncheck the green box, then it goes into function and does what it has to do. can you give an explanation for why it does that?

Comment: Hi again. unfortunately it stil doesn't add it to the html code when i inspect the source code from safari. like it doesn't make a style="width 50%;" in source unless i check/uncheck the green one. unfortunately. can you try it in a single html page? i dont think fiddle allows you to use cookies there to se the result.

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxajL3hv/2/) for you. Removed some of the functionality in your example, but hopefully the essence is there. Also, I don't think it answers your question perfectly, but it's a place to start if you want to make changes based on which box is checked.
The essence is quite simple, just use a event listener to do modifications to the css of the individual divs you want to edit:

```
redEl.on("change",function(){
    <your logic here>
});
```

Hope this helps